# Core Animation: set anchorPoint on 10.8 to rotate a layer about its center

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation, core-graphics

**NB: This is for a Cocoa app on OS X, NOT iOS.**

I have a layer-backed NSButton (subclass of NSView). What I want to do is rotate that button using Core Animation. I'm using the following code to do it:

```
CABasicAnimation *a = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
a.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
a.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-M_PI*2];
[_refreshButton.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
a.duration = 1.8; // seconds
a.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
[_refreshButton.layer addAnimation:a forKey:nil];
```

This works, EXCEPT that when it runs, the layer jumps down and to the left so that its center point is at the origin point of the NSView, which is the lower-left corner at (0,0). The layer then rotates about its center, but obviously the jumping-to-the-lower-left-corner is not acceptable.

So, after much reading, I found this line in the 10.8 API release notes:

```
On 10.8, AppKit will control the following properties on a CALayer 
(both when "layer-hosted" or "layer-backed"): geometryFlipped, bounds, 
frame (implied), position, anchorPoint, transform, shadow*, hidden, 
filters, and compositingFilter. Use the appropriate NSView cover methods 
to change these properties.
```

This means that AppKit is "ignoring" my call to -setAnchorPoint in the code above and, instead, is setting that anchor point to the NSView's origin (0,0).

My question is: how do I solve this? What is the "appropriate NSView cover method" to set the anchorPoint for the layer (I can't find such a method on NSView). At the end of the day, I just want my button to rotate around its center point, indefinitely.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't see any methods on `NSView` that are a direct “cover” for `anchorPoint`.

What I do see in [the 10.8 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html), besides what you quoted, is this:

> The anchorPoint is also always set to be (0,0), …

The `anchorPoint` controls which point of the layer is at `position` in the superlayer's coordinate system.  `NSView` sets `self.layer.anchorPoint` to (0,0), which means the layer's lower-left corner is at `self.layer.position`.

When you set `anchorPoint` to (0.5,0.5), that means the center of the layer should be at the layer's `position`.  Since you didn't modify `position`, this has the effect of moving the layer down and to the left, as you are seeing.

You need to compute the `position` you want the layer to have when its `anchorPoint` is (0.5,0.5), like this:

```
CGRect frame = _refreshButton.layer.frame;
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame));
_refreshButton.layer.position = center;
_refreshButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
```

Comment: Perfect! You know; I saw the position property but didn't give it a try because I read the note above that says AppKit is going to control it. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Any idea why the rotation M_PI/2 would rotate counter clockwise the first time and clockwise after that?

Comment: I would have to see your code.  You should post your own question.

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623725/cabasicanimation-rotating-wrong-direction-first-time

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same problem as @Bryan in Swift: the object would jump away from its original position during animation. Here's the code for a pulsing NSButton for macOS:

```
  let frame : CGRect = startButton.layer!.frame
  let center : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
  startButton.layer?.position = center;
  startButton.layer?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        
  let pulse = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
  pulse.duration = 0.2
  pulse.fromValue = 0.95
  pulse.toValue = 1.0
  pulse.autoreverses = true
  pulse.repeatCount = 10
  pulse.initialVelocity = 0.5
  pulse.damping = 1.0
        
  startButton.layer?.add(pulse, forKey: "pulse")
```